# Access scala/spark constructor in clojure

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I want to access the constructor from the class `StructField` which is present in the package `org.apache.spark.sql.types` as shown in their github [repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v1.5.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types). So just for testing I imported the classes in clojure like this:

```
(ns user 
  (:import [org.apache.spark.sql.types StructField DoubleType]))
```

But when I call `StructField`'s constructor by passing in the two necessary arguments like this:

```
(StructField. "a" DoubleType)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: are you sure that constructor exists? the only one I find has two more arguments you don't provide https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.html

Comment: @noisesmith Those two arguments are optional and need as they already have a default value hardcoded. You can take a look at its source code by visiting their github link that I have provided in my question. And BTW, I have already done it in scala. Just can't understand why it does not work in clojure.

Comment: scala does a lot of things that java and other jvm langs do not, if it doesn't work from java, it won't work from clojure. My strong suspicion is that the optional args created by those annotations are a scala feature that doesn't exist in the bytecode, and therefor to use the constructor from clojure you will need to provide those arguments.

Comment: Okay I'll try filling in all the args.